# When is MVC no longer applicable in large projects?

Tags: model-view-controller, kohana, models

Having used some PHP frameworks such as Codeigniter and Kohana for some smaller sites, I'm starting to wonder if MVC is still applicable for larger projects and, if so, what precautions need to be taken to maintain clean clode. What practices do the larger sites use in order to prevent this? Does Amazon's or Flickr's code use MVC or some variant of it? Is there a guide that, given a certain problem, shows you how best to implement MVC for large projects?

-- Tangent --

On a current project using Kohana, I started to question what role my models should have. Often times, a model can only describe a small part of an object that I'm trying to build. I.e., need an object for a User, so I extract my user from the Users table using my Users_Model. But each user also has several items in their inventory, so I need to also use the Users_Inventory_Model.  But, each inventory item also has other tables associated with it, and so on, until I find that building up a single User in my controller has required me to access several models. Now, imagine doing this in many different controllers and suddenly I find myself with messy and redundant code and very fat controllers.

This led me to think that maybe I should have libraries which handle most of the grunt work. That way, I could have a Users library and let it load all of my pertinent user data and run most of the logic such as updating, deleting, etc. Is this the way most MVC projects evolve? Letting libraries do most of the interaction with the models, while the controllers call the libraries and prepare the data for the views? Anyway, this is just one of the questions I've had about MVC, which I haven't been able to find an answer to online.

Comment: Well, stackoverflow.com is built with mvc :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, it's for big projects where all these MVPs and MVCs really shine. All software design patterns are "created" (besides establishing common vocabulary) to deal with complexity of software. Thus, used properly, MVC will be of great help to you in big projects.

Contrast with small apps, which can be hacked together with mouse-only approach, but are a nightmare to support since there's no proper separation nor they're [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) enough.

Comment: Is the PPP book linked in that article worth reading or can I find equivalent material online?